# Show that a function if $p_i\rightarrow p_0\Rightarrow f(p_i)$ converges, $f$ is continuous at $p_0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I was asked to prove the following statement:

Let $(E,d),(E',d')$ be metric spaces. $f:E\rightarrow E'$ is continuous at $p_0$ if for every sequence $(p_n)\in E$ converging to $p_0$, $f(p_n)$ converges.

Here's how I attempted to prove this statement: Assume $f$ is not continuous at $p_0$. Then $\exists \epsilon>0$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists p_n\subset E$ such that $d(p_n,p_0)<1/n$ and $d'(f(p_n),f(p_0))\geq \epsilon$. Then $(p_n)$ converges to $p_0$ and $(f(p_n))$ does not converge to $f(p_0)$. However, how can I show that $(f(p_n))$ does not converge at all? Is it possible for $(f(p_n))$ to converge to some other point?

Comment: Yes it can converge to some other point

Comment: @ Sambo I see. I will inform my instructor about it.

Comment: @Sambo the statement is not false and your example is not a counterexample

Comment: @Andrew would you please explain a bit more? What is the correct statement here?

Comment: @Andrew What are you talking about? By definition of continuity at $p_0$, the limit must be $f(p_0)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin in any case, a function with a simple discontinuity is not a counterexample to the claim. Take the sequence $0,1/2,0,1/3,0,1/4,0,1/5,...$ If a function has a simple discontinuity at $0$, then $x_n\to 0$ whereas $f(x_n)$ does not converge

Comment: @TedShifrin it is not at all obvious to me the claim is false, so if you have a counterexample, please share it

Answer (score 1):

I think I know how to prove it. We can define a sequence where $p_n=p_0$ for $n$ odd and $p_n$ such that $d(p_n,p_0)<1/n$ for $n$ even. Then $(f(p_n))$ can't converge to $f(p_0)$ or any other point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_n\to p$ and $\tilde p_n \to p$. If $\lim f(p_n) \neq \lim f(\tilde p_n)$, then consider the sequence $\hat p_n = p_{2n}$ and $\hat p_{n} = \tilde p_{2n+1}$. It follows that $\lim f(\hat p_n)$ does not exist, contrary to our hypothesis. The thesis follows.